# Make search bar visible in mobile view

Tags: search, magento2.2.3

Can someone explain to me how I can make the search bar to be consistently there and the magnifying icon does not need to be clicked to make it appear in mobile view?

My theme is based on **Luma**, **Magento version 2.2.3**

**What is currently there (you need to click the search icon to make the search bar appear):**
[image: Current View]

**What I want:**
[image: What I want]

Then I will just code it so the bar scales depending on the viewport.

Comment: You can manage it through css. No need to do extra coding.

Comment: It is what I'm having trouble with.. How do I get rid of the search icon and make the bar appear?

Comment: Are you using any different theme or luma?

Comment: I do have a custom theme that is using Luma as the fallback. I'm only changing small things like colours etc and haven't done anything major.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add the below lines to your css:

```
.block-search .minisearch input#search{position:static;}
.block-search .minisearch .label{display:none;}
```

It works for me on luma theme. Use the above code under media query. Not for desktop.

Comment: This got rid of the magnifying glass but how do I show the search bar instead?

Comment: Both should work. You need add position static to your input field.

Comment: Yes, thank you, marking it as correct, much appreciated!